# what is the word for using a thing without the other person's consent

Tags: single-word-requests

I seem to require a verb for using a person's thing without his consent.
Maybe hijack or something.

Comment: I guess you do not want "steal"?  Sometimes we say "borrow" to make it seem less like stealing.

Comment: When cops do it to cars, it’s known as *comandeering*; when juvenile delinquents do it, it’s known as *joyriding* ;)

Comment: What did your dictionaries and theasuruses leave unclear, please?

Comment: TWOCing - Taking without consent. _He twoced his Dad's Ferrari and wrapped it round a lamppost_.

Comment: @NigelJ That would be twocked or twocced.

Comment: @PhilSweet I was guessing, I have never seen it written down, only heard it spoken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [(oxforddictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/appropriate)
>    **appropriate**
>   Take (something) for one's own use, **typically without the owner's permission**
>    *‘the accused had appropriated the property’*

Answer (score 2):

[Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/misappropriate) is admittedly unusual in licensing the 'use without permission' in addition to the more common 'steal' sense of **misappropriate**:

> When you misappropriate something, you steal it, or otherwise use it
>   in a way its owner didn't intend.

Comment: Haha -  perhaps some people feel more comfortable including the ***mis-*** prefix in case anyone mistakenly assumes the relevant unauthorised appropriation was actually *appropriate = **right and proper***.

Comment: Have an erable day.

Comment: Us creants are used to being erable - ["This is hell, nor am I out of it".](http://www.ucs.mun.ca/~dhallett/2002/NotesW4.htm)

Answer (score 1):

A legalistic term is **conversion**.

> Conversion is an intentional tort. It is, "taking with the intent of exercising over the chattel an ownership inconsistent with the real owner's right of possession".[1] In the United Kingdom, it is a tort of strict liability.[2] Its equivalents in criminal law include larceny or theft and criminal conversion. In those jurisdictions that recognise it, criminal conversion is a lesser crime than theft/larceny.
>
> Examples of conversion include: 1) Alpha cuts down and hauls away
>   trees on land s/he knows is owned by Beta, without permission or
>   privilege to do so; and 2) Gamma takes furniture belonging to Delta
>   and puts it into storage, without Delta's consent (and especially if
>   Delta does not know where Gamma put it). A common act of conversion in
>   medieval times involved bolts of cloth that were bailed for
>   safekeeping, which the bailee or a third party took and made clothes
>   for their own use or for sale.

Wikipedia conversion (law) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(law)

The verb, of course is *convert*.

Comment: 'Using without the owner's consent' does not entail that the tool etc is not returned in at least as good a condition as it was in before being taken. For instance, a lawnmower may be used for a few minutes, then maintained, oiled, fuelled and cleaned, and then returned. The examples given above look more like theft to me.

Comment: The bailee didn't steal the bolts of cloth, they were given to him. What he did was deny the owner the right to determine how they would be used. The cutter didn't steal the real estate, but he did deny the owner the right to manage the estate as he saw fit. If the cutter just wanted to mitigate hazard trees or improve their own view of the valley, they can't really be gotten for theft.

Comment: 'Bailed for safekeeping' looks like 'put in secure storage, a fee being paid' to me; using the property for personal gain, at the depositor's expense, theft.

Answer (score 0):

**theft**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/theft)

> a. The unlawful taking of the property of another; larceny: